# Hibernate connection time is so long when connecting remote MySQL Server

Tags: java, mysql, performance, hibernate, time

This is my `hibernate.cfg.xml`. I use `c3p0` pooling library.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://sample:3306</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sample</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">sample</property>
    <property name="connection.provider_class">org.jasypt.hibernate4.connectionprovider.EncryptedPasswordDriverManagerConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.encryptor_registered_name">hibernateEncryptor</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">sample</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">3</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1;</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

The connection time is taking so long to the remote MySQL Server. Please help, thanks!

Comment: Improve expression

Comment: simplify the configuration to the bare minimums, make sure the problem is hibernate, and if it is start adding properties until things break; in particular, I'd remove connection pooling before anything else.  If it's slow with a minimal config, then I'd question your MySQL configuration or the network